# How do I pass arguments by nodeJS express app route

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Currently I have two files:

service.js

```
const routes = (app) => {
  app.route('/produce')
    .get((req, res) => res.send(`GET Method from /produce`))
    .post((req, res) => res.send(req.body))
};

module.exports = routes;
```

app.js

```
const service = require('./service.js');
service(app);
```

After that, when I try to 'GET', it returns the text "GET Method from /produce" as expected

However, when I try to 'POST' some message, it cannot return my request message.

Anyone can help on this? Many thanks.

Comment: what's the response of the POST action? is it a 404 error or 200 with unexpected message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact code you pasted doesn't work because it fails to stringify the `req` object. Check the [express API](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) and decide what exactly information you want to get from the `req` object.

For example:

```
.post((req, res) => res.send(req.body))
```

To get `req.body` working you need to set up a body-parsing middleware such as express.json() or express.urlencoded().

For example, if you are working with `application/json`, try something like

```
app.use(express.json())
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, but it seems not working....
Further check the log and it says the req.body is undefined....

Comment: the `req.body` is undefined unless you use body-parsing middleware such as express.json() or express.urlencoded(). something like `app.use(express.json())`.  But that's just an example, pls check the express API link for more details...

Comment: Thx for the hint! 
I miss out `app.use(express.json())` in the service.js file
After I include the code, it works fine, again, thx for your help.